# Substitution in integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory

I am working on a probability theory excercise and encountered the following integral: 
$$
\iint_{(x,y)\in A}\frac{1}{2}(x+y)e^{-(x+y)}dA,
$$
where  $A = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\,x+y\le z\,;\, x,y\ge0\}$.

I can calculate this the hard way by saying it is equal to 
$$
\int_{0}^{z}\int_{0}^{z-x}\frac{1}{2}(x+y)e^{-(x+y)}dydx.
$$
However this is a bothersome work, and the form of the integral gives me the idea that it can be done in a more simple way. Namely: By substituting $u=x+y$ in some way. Now I am familiar with substitutions and have used them plentiful, but I have never dealt with a substitution where I replace two variables by only one. By not thinking and just doing I thought it might be equal to
$$
\int_{0}^{z}\frac{1}{2}ue^{-u}du,
$$
but I believe this to be wrong. Can someone give me a push in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $(x,y)$ by $(u,v)=(x+y,x)$. Then the domain $x\geqslant0$, $y\geqslant0$, $x+y\leqslant z$ becomes $z\geqslant u\geqslant v\geqslant0$ and the Jacobian is $1$ hence your integral becomes
$$
\int_0^z\frac12u\mathrm e^{-u}\int_0^u\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du.
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you! Yes from here I will manage:)

Answer (score 1):

You want to introduce a change of variables $$(x,y)\to (s,t)$$$$s=x+y,\quad t=x-y.$$ $$x= \frac 12 (s+t),\quad y= \frac 12 (s-t),$$
so $$dA=dx\wedge dy = \frac 14 (ds+dt)\wedge(ds-dt)=\frac 12 dt\wedge ds.$$

Therefore, your integral becomes

$$\int_A\frac 12 s e^{-s}dt\,ds = \frac 14 \int_0^{z}  \left(\int_{-s}^{s} se^{-s}dt\right) ds$$

Comment: @Marc you are welcome!